# How to translate a lambda expression to normal code? c#

Tags: java, c#, list, lambda, where-clause

I need to use this code in .net Framework 2.0 but the problem is that labmdas(WHERE) can't be used in this version, is there a way?

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
retorno = serializer.Deserialize<RespuestaCvt>(respuesta);

var soloServidores = retorno.Rows.Where(x => listaEstados.Contains(x.EstadoId)).Where(x => listaTipos.Contains(x.TipoId)).ToList();
                                return soloServidores;
```

Comment: how did you get in the weird situation to use c# 2.0 in 2020?

Comment: Iterate the rows, check the conditions, add the coincident ones to a list. Done. Also, that query... why two `where`s? `Where(x => listaEstados.Contains(x.EstadoId) && listaTipos.Contains(x.TipoId))` That will make more clear which conditions ou must check.

Comment: @curiosa it's part of the job hehehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Lambda expressions were not available until C# 3 you will have to change the way you do the actual row filtering. Since you're returning `List<>` we can just go back to the pre-LINQ way of doing things:

```
var soloServidores = new List<TheRowType>();
foreach (var row in retorno.Rows)
{
    if (listaEstados.Contains(row.EstadoId) && listaTipos.Contains(x.TopiId))
        soloServidores.Add(row);
}
return soloServidores;
```

Of course you could do it the hard way and extract the lambda to a static method then implement a suitable `Where(...)` extension... but if you're going to try to emulate C# features from a later language version then you're usually better off migrating your project to that later version.

Comment: thank you so much bro, it works , it's perfect!!!!